# What in-game methods eliminate or disperse Fog Cloud?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [Fog Cloud](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fog-cloud) spell description says:

> You create a 20-foot-radius sphere of fog centered on a point within
>   range. The sphere spreads around corners, and its area is heavily
>   obscured. It lasts for the duration or until a wind of moderate or
>   greater speed (at least 10 miles per hour) disperses it.

What are all the ways of eliminating Fog from the battlefield in 5e? I'm looking for spells, special abilities, animal forms, and the like; all are valid answers.

Answer (score 9):

Anything that makes "Strong Wind" will clear fog. Some spells that create strong wind include:

- [Gust of Wind](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gust%20of%20Wind#content) (2nd Level, Wizard, Druid, Sorcerer): disperses fog and gas in a 60' line and can keep blowing for up to a minute with concentration
- [Wind Wall](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wind%20Wall#content) (3rd Level, Druid, Ranger) creates a 60' long wall that, among other things, "keeps fog, smoke, and other gases at bay" for up to a minute with concentration
- If you're outdoors, [Control Weather](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Control%20Weather#toc_2) (8th Lever, Cleric, Druid, Wizard) could create a strong wind to disperse fog, though it takes several minutes to take effect.

Another related possibility that makes sense, but relies on DM fiat, is:

- [Thunderwave](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Thunderwave#content) (1st Level, Bard, Druid, Sorcerer, Wizard) which makes a "wave of thunderous force" that knocks creatures and unsecured objects back by 10'. RAW, fog is neither a creature or an object, but realistically, you'd expect any force sufficient to knock a person back would also disperse fog in that radius.

Additionally, as PixelMaster points out, Fog Cloud has duration "Concentration", so if you disrupt the spell, the fog will disappear:

- [Counterspell](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Counterspell#h-Counterspell), if cast as a reaction when you see the caster begin casting, will automatically cause the spell to fail
- [Dispel Magic](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Dispel%20Magic#content) (3rd Level, Bard, Cleric, Druid, Paladin, Sorcerer, Warlock, Wizard) Can end one magical effect of 3rd level or lower automatically (Fog Cloud is 1st level)
- Simply use any effect to deal damage to the caster until they fail a Concentration check

Comment: you can also Dispel-Magic it, or Counterspell it in the first place.

Comment: You could also incapacitate the spellcaster (e.g. with *Tasha’s Hideous Laughter*, though that requires you to be able to see them) to break their concentration. And one other option (though it's an absurdly high cost for a 1st level spell) would be *Antimagic Field*.

Answer (score 5):

I think my players found perhaps the lowest level spell that would work RAW, unless someone wants to make an argument for the [Gust](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gust) cantrip.

[Create or Destroy Water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/create-or-destroy-water) lvl 1, available to Clerics and Druids

> Destroy Water. You destroy up to 10 gallons of water in an open
>   container within range. Alternatively, you destroy fog in a 30-foot
>   cube within range.